# How can I get events conversion from Firebase analytics by BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I try to get a number of events, and conversion for each event from Firebase analytics on a specific date through BigQuery.

I spent a lot of time to search on Google but I did not find any suitable answer. Please help.

Comment: Hi, please share some example code so that we can see what you have already tried.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any idea for query event conversion


But for number of events, I get by query 

```
SELECT count(event_name) AS event_count 
FROM `trueyou-edc.analytics_162983372.events_20190929` 
WHERE event_name = "screen_view"; 
```

Answer (score 0):

[There is plenty of documentation regarding both conversions itself](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en) and [using BigQuery for Firebase Analysis](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9037342?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512#)

If you read through the second, you will find there are some query examples that will probably help you.

Comment: Hi Albert, please notice that posting only links isn't the preferred way of answering on SO. Just have a look to the Help Center regarding [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.